# How to set node name in WildFly-8.2.0 domain mode

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-8

I can set this in standalone mode by using `-Djboss.node.name=nodeA`. I wonder, how can this be set for each node managed in domain mode?

I found that there is a small change in the node name when it is in domain mode compared to standalone mode. In standalone mode it is `nodeA` but in domain mode it is `master:nodeA`. Is there any way to make them the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're seeing in domain mode is the **fully qualified name**. It is telling you the host name, followed by the node name.

If you look in your `host-master.xml`, you will see the root tag looks like this:

```
<host name="master" xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:2.2">
```

If you change the host name to something like `main`, you will find that your fully qualified node name is `main:nodeA`.

You could remove the `name` attribute from the `<host>` (the `host.xml` file doesn't have it), but I wouldn't recommend it, because it can make things a bit more confusing in terms of management if you have a multiple hosts.

Comment: I understood that. I am checking whether I can set a name that will be same in both nodes. Even if I removed name attribute from the <host>, it will use the machine name as the host name.

Comment: @Valsaraj am facing the same situation, did you find a solution.

Comment: @Francis, I didn't check on that since we are using host:node name.

Answer (score 1):

this solution works for me
first go to host.xml add this system property under

```
 <servers>    
  <server name="server-one" group="main-server-group">
        <socket-bindings port-offset="150"/>
        <system-properties>
            <property name="jboss.node.name" value="nodeA" boot-time="true"/>
        </system-properties>
  </server>
  .....
 </servers>
```

second go to domain.xml and under every profile entry search for

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:transactions:1.5">
```

and change the core-element tag as shown below

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:transactions:1.5">
    <core-environment node-identifier="${jboss.node.name}">
        ...
    </core-environment>
    ...
</subsystem>
```